# Textbox not plotting on matplotlib figure

Tags: python, user-interface, matplotlib, pyqt5

I have an issue when I run the following script it does not complete the `self.add_box` command in the `assign_text()` function. I have tested it and it does go through the `add_box()` function completely, it just does not plot the textbox on the figure. Any help would be appreciated!

What I expect to happen is it opens 2 windows, first is a pyplot figure and the second is a QWidget. When you hit the button on the QWidget it should put a new textbox on the pyplot figure. Right now, you hit the button and nothing new gets put on the pyplot figure.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QPushButton
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Failure_Tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.ax.set_xlim([0, 100])
        self.ax.set_ylim([0, 100])
        self.fig.show()

    def add_box(self, text, posx, posy):
        # these are matplotlib.patch.Patch properties
        props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=1)
        # place a text box
        self.ax.text(posx, posy, text, bbox=props, fontsize=14, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')

    def window(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.w = QWidget()

        self.w.resize(640, 480)

        self.textBox = QPlainTextEdit(self.w)
        self.textBox.move(250, 120)

        button = QPushButton("click me", self.w)
        button.move(20, 80)

        self.w.show()

        button.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.assign_text())

    def assign_text(self):
        text = self.textBox.document().toPlainText()
        self.add_box('hello World', 50, 50)
        self.w.close()


F = Failure_Tree()
F.window()
F.add_box('Bye World!', 0, 0)
```

Update:

I have solved the original issue, but now an issue happens when I run the code in IDLE. The updated code is below, it works perfectly in Spyder but crashes in IDLE after the new textbox is created.

```
import sys
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QWidget, QPlainTextEdit, QPushButton
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

class Failure_Tree():
    def __init__(self):
        self.fig, self.ax = plt.subplots()
        self.ax.set_xlim([0, 100])
        self.ax.set_ylim([0, 100])
        self.fig.show()

    def add_box(self, text, posx, posy):
        # these are matplotlib.patch.Patch properties
        props = dict(boxstyle='round', facecolor='wheat', alpha=1)
        # place a text box
        self.ax.text(posx, posy, text, bbox=props, fontsize=14, horizontalalignment='center', verticalalignment='center')

        self.fig.canvas.draw()

    def window(self):
        self.app = QApplication(sys.argv)
        self.w = QWidget()

        self.w.resize(640, 480)

        self.textBox = QPlainTextEdit(self.w)
        self.textBox.move(250, 120)

        button = QPushButton("click me", self.w)
        button.move(20, 80)

        self.w.show()

        button.clicked.connect(
            lambda: self.assign_text())


    def assign_text(self):

        text = self.textBox.document().toPlainText()
        self.add_box('hello World', 50, 50)
        self.w.close()
        self.app.exec_()


F = Failure_Tree()
F.window()
F.add_box('Bye World!', 0, 0)
```

Comment: You forgot to redraw the figure after changing it. `self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()`.

Comment: thank you! this seems to have fixed this issue, however only in Spyder. When I run it in IDLE it does not work and instead restarts the shell as soon as it gets to the line `self.fig.canvas.draw_idle()`.  Any idea why?

Comment: You could try `self.fig.canvas.draw()` instead. But I suspect the real problem is that you do not execute the qt program in the usual way, namely to keep it active until closed. `qapp.exec_()`

Comment: `self.fig.canvas.draw()` works perfectly! When I use `qapp.exec_()` it actually brings the problem back. I click the button, it writes the textbox to self.fig, closes the QApp window, then crashes the shell. If you would like to post a corrected version how you would use `qapp.exec_()` as an answer I will mark it the solution.

Comment: I cannot reproduce your problem (the one in IDLE) so I don't know why it would fail and hence cannot provide any solution to that.

Comment: okay, no problem. Thanks for your help! If you would like the solution reputation feel free to post your original comment as one and I will mark it.

Comment: Thanks, but I feel I have enough reputation points. ;-) Rather edit the question with the unsolved problem and leave it unanswered, maybe someone can reproduce and give a complete answer at some point in the future.